# document.getElementById("id").value , change id by adding a variable to it

Tags: javascript, html

```
function totalCost(obj,a){    
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;             
}
```

I want to create a new *id* adding variable a. If `a =1`, then the next *id* will be `price1`. How can I do it?

Comment: `"price" + a` ?

Comment: [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)?

Comment: My apologies, could you be more precise about what you are trying to achieve? What is your goal?

Comment: "price" + a works fine .  Thanks @Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows embedded expressions:

```
function totalCost(obj,a){    
   var price = document.getElementById(`price${a}`).value;             
}
```

**OR:** Using String Concatenation (if browser is yet to support Template Literals)

```
function totalCost(obj,a){    
  var price = document.getElementById('price' + a).value;             
}
```

Comment: Template literals is an ES6 feature and are still not supported by all the browsers(IE11[https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals]). So always suggest them as an alternative syntax.

Comment: @ShakirUzZaman, you can post comment if the answer does not solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
function totalCost(obj,a)
     {    
       var price = document.getElementById("price"+a).value;              
     }
```

this solution is working fine .